# Proving that ∼(∃x) P (x), is false is equivalent to proving that (∀x )∼P (x) is true.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I found this phrase in the page 60 of the book "A Transition to Advanced Mathematics, 8th Edition, written by Smith/Eggen/St. Andre."

"Proving that ∼(∃x) P (x), is false is equivalent to proving that (∀x )∼P (x) is true."

It seems incorrect to me, but as I am a student, I guess that I am wrong.

My reasoning is that if we work with the equation of the right side:

(∀x)∼P(x) is true, we can see it as

("(∀x)∼P (x) =  true") and this would be equal to

("∼ ((∀x)∼P (x)) =  ∼(true)")=

(∃x)P(x) = false.

then  (∃x)P(x) is false.

That is the opposite of our goal.

Am I wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The book is wrong, in fact those two statements are the 'opposite' of each other.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Then, is my reasoning correct?

Comment: I don't really like how you wrote it, but the idea behind it is certainly correct.

Comment: Thanks! May you tell me how would be the correct way to write it?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean $\neg$ where that ~ is?

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a shot of the relevant excerpt of the book to the question. However this was taken from the seventh edition and might not coincide with what you have (please check it). If the text is the same, then you misinterpreted what was said, the book is not wrong.

Comment: @barakmanos $\sim$ is a not so uncommon symbol for the negation.

Comment: @GitGud: $\neg\exists{x}:{P(x)}$ is in fact equivalent to $\forall{x}:\neg{P(x)}$. So the only problem with that statement at the title is the `is false`, which looks more like a typo.

Comment: @GitGud I checked the amazon preview of the 8th edition. (http://www.amazon.com/Transition-Advanced-Mathematics-Douglas-Smith/dp/1285463269#reader_1285463269). Sentence appears in the book as in the title of OP. Although the page preview of that page does not work, so I could only see a small excerpt.

Comment: @barakmanos The statement in the title is false. Reread it.

Comment: @sanjab Thanks. WTF is up with the price of that book? What a travesty.

Comment: @GitGud: What part of what I said did you miss? I said it was false, but it looked false only because of the `is false`, which looked like a typo.

Comment: @Beginner Regarding how to write it, you use the equal sign too freely. For instance in `("(∀x)∼P (x) =  true") and this would be equal to ("∼ ((∀x)∼P (x)) =  ∼(true)"` I'd replace the first equal sign by the word 'is', I'd replace the word 'equal' by 'equivalent' and I'd replace the last equal sign by 'is'.

Comment: @barakmanos $\sim$ for negation has been common since the 19th century. That is the symbol used in Whitehead and Russell's *Principia Mathematica* for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See page 56 of seventh edition :

> There are times when we will want to prove a quantified statement is *false*. We know that $(\forall x)P(x)$ is false precisely when $\lnot (\forall x)P(x)$ is true and $\lnot (\forall x)P(x)$ is equivalent to $(\exists x) \lnot P(x)$. Therefore, one way to prove $(\forall x)P(x)$ is false is to prove $(\exists x) \lnot P(x)$ is true.

Thus, if $\lnot (\exists x) P(x)$ is *false*, its negation : $(\exists x) P(x)$ must be *true*; but $(\exists x) P(x)$ is equivalent to $\lnot (\forall x) \lnot P(x)$.

In conclusion, you are right; alternatively, we can say that :

> Proving that $\lnot (∃x)P(x)$, is false is equivalent to proving that $\lnot (∀x) \lnot P(x)$ is true.

As per comments above, the statement in the 2014 edition must be a typo.

Comment: @Beginner - see my edied answer; I do not agree ... it must be a typo.

Comment: Thanks, I was crazy trying to understand the phrase!